# Home.php not working with underscores

Tags: theme-development

I have a clean install with reading settings set to static page and blog index set to a page named 'Blog'.  According to the codex home.php should be the template in use for the blog index, but instead it is using 'page.php'.  Why could this be?  I have no plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

Review the 'WordPress Theme Hierarchy' document here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

It explains how templates are selected according to function and availability. The chart is helpful.

Comment: According to the Template Hierarchy, OP is right, `home.php` should be used. So the question is, why is `page.php` being used instead?

Comment: Then the theme is doing something different. No word on the theme, but if the problem doesn't happen with another theme, then it it a theme issue. Or an issue with the template OP may have chosen for a page (if a Page is set as the home page).